# Updating changed value on user interface

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want my value to change on the screen when button is pressed. It does change the variable value behind the scenes but has no effect for the outdated value shown on the screen.

```
export default class App extends Component {
render() {
this.state = {
  myVariable: 'egs'
}
const changeValue = () => {
  this.state.myVariable = "CHANGED??!!"
}
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>
      {this.state.myVariable}
    </Text>
    <Button onPress={changeValue} title="CHANGE IT"/>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

I expect to update value to the changed one instead of outdated one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move state initialization outside of render as well as the changeValue method

You also cannot mutate statue directly, instead use setState()

This should work:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        myVariable: 'egs'
    }
    changeValue = () => {
        this.setState({myVariable:"CHANGED??!!"})
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>
                    {this.state.myVariable}
                </Text>
                <Button onPress={changeValue} title="CHANGE IT"/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You're a life saver.... Was struggling with this for couple of days. Worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: @HumanCode Yeah, state initialization is usually done on the component like above or in a constructor. The reason is the constructor is only called once when the component is instantiated whereas the render function is called any time there is a state change.

Comment: also just fyi if you are initializing more than state before first render use contructor anything needing to be initialized after first render should be done in componentdidmount

Answer (score 0):

```
this.state.myVariable = "CHANGED??!!"
```

change to

```
this.setState({ myVariable: "CHANGED??!!" })
```

Comment: Just tried it out, still doesn't change the value on the display. Also it does not change value of the variable.